# Extract piped list of dbid's in r

Tags: r

A complete novice in r. Somehow, I've managed to get this far in my data manipulation so don't anyone destroy me!

I'm looking to extract a piped list of DB ids from a column of 'cat', that I'm querying using 'lookup' and paste it into the output file 'out'

```
lookup<-read.csv("lookup.csv",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE, fill=TRUE)
```

'lookup.csv' is like this

```
activity                verb

gap junction channel    connects  
recombinase             binds  
activator               activates  
binding                 binds
kinase adaptor          binds  
DNA clamp loader        binds
branching               branches  
carboxylase             carboxylates  
nuclease                cleaves  
peptidase               cleaves  
aldolase                cleaves  
heparanase              cleaves  
radical SAM enzyme      cleaves  
endopeptidase           cleaves  
dihydroorotase          cleaves  
N-glycosylase           cleaves  
glycosylase             cleaves  
symporter               co-transports  
cyclase                 converts  
transhydrogenase        converts  
deacetylase             deacetylates  
decarboxylase           decarboxylates  
catalase                decomposes  
dehydratase             dehydrates
```

Dump my target file into 'cat', which also has empty activity rows, I fill with NA

```
cat<-read.csv("molecules3.csv",header=TRUE,
     stringsAsFactors=FALSE, fill=TRUE, na.strings = c(""," ","NA"))
```

'molecules3.csv' is like this

```
dbid    function

6787677 racemase and epimerase activity, acting on carbohydrates and derivatives
6787642 GDP-L-fucose synthase activity
6787632 GDP-mannose 4,6-dehydratase activity
6787623 isomerase activity
6787594 tRNA (adenine-N1-)-methyltransferase activity
6787591 tRNA (guanine-N1-)-methyltransferase activity
6787567 tRNA dimethylallyltransferase activity
6787566 pseudouridine synthase activity
6787540 fucokinase activity
6787533 fucose-1-phosphate guanylyltransferase activity
6787525 tRNA (adenine-N1-)-methyltransferase activity
6787447 tRNA-5-taurinomethyluridine 2-sulfurtransferase
6787403 transferase activity|transferase activity
6787329 phosphopentomutase activity
6787321 deoxyribose-phosphate aldolase activity
6786881 RNA polymerase activity
6786854 tRNA-specific ribonuclease activity|ribonuclease P activity
```

I store activities and reaction type in a variable

```
#Activities are in column 1, reaction type is in column 2
f<- unique(factor(lookup[,1])) 
v<- factor(lookup[,2])
```

I constructed a data frame to house the results of a ‘for’ loop

```
out<-data.frame("Activity"=character(0), "numberActivities"=numeric(0),     "rows"=numeric(0), "DBIDs"=numeric(0), "ReactionType"=character(0),     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


# loop over each row and determine number of activities for each unique activity
for (i in 1:length(f)){     #for each unique activity
out[i,1]<-as.character(f[i])            #store activity
out[i,2]<-length(grep(f[i],cat[,2]))    # store length of matched activity
out[i,3]<-paste(grep(f[i],cat[,2]),collapse="|") #store position of row matches

out[i,5]<-paste(v[i])               #paste in the corresponding reaction type for each activity
```

The 'out' file is like this

```
    Activity    numberActivities rows   DBIDs   ReactionType

101 kinase      1164    6|12|23|24|31…  NA      phosphorylates
114 transferase 892     1|46|48|55|56…  NA      transfers
11  peptidase   483     35|38|51|81|85… NA      cleaves
```

and so on.

To fill out[i,4], I want a list of ‘dbid’s for each type of activity, separated by ‘|’.

out[i,3] does exactly that but filled with row numbers.

How do I fill the 4th column with a list of dbid's?

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `cat` as an object name. It's a basic R function name.  This is an (untested) implementation of the `l/sapply( split(.,.) , FUN)`-paradigm for managing problems where you want calculations based within segments of dataframes that share a particular characteristic (activities in this case):

```
 temp <- sapply( split( categ, categ$Activities) , 
                 function( db) c(Activities=db$Activities[1], # use the first row as a label
                                 numberActivities= nrow(db), # get the count
                                  rows=paste0(db$Activities,collapse="|") )
         # Have concerns about the length of these results but it's what you asked for
                 )
final<- merge( temp, lookup)
```

Better answer can be given when an actual sample is offered that can support testing. Yours at the moment is not sufficient for that purpose, so this code is untested.

Comment: If it is correct to do so on this site, I can send you the files I start with which have all the data that I read into this script. How do I make these available to you?

Comment: The usual method is to provide a link to a public "dropbox", although making dataframes of the data you have might work. Generally one would use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when working with text .

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to find out what I need to do and have the answer!